# Showing a function is constant given $f_{xx} + f_{yy} \geq 0$ on the domain.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Saw this question when looking through an old vector calculus text and wasn't able to find a reasonably formal way of proving the following assertion: Let $f \in C^2$,  $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and suppose that:
$$ \frac{\partial^2  f }{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y^2} \geq 0 \qquad \forall (x,y) \in U $$
Prove that if $f$ has a local maximum at a point $(a,b) \in U$, then $f(x,y)=constant$.
While I figure one can argue this geometrically, I am not sure what tools to use to make prove the result. Thanks.

Comment: Your function would be called "subharmonic". There is a mean value inequality for such functions.